# Saving response as a attachments in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In one of my projects, I am hitting external API which giving response as "application/zip" and I need to send the same response to the client so the response can be saved into a file and then the user unzip it and use it. The same scenario is working as expected from postman however from node code the file is generated as corrupted. Following is a code snippet from my cntroller where I am pulling zip data from the API

```
Service.getZipFileContent(userData, key).then(response=> {
            res.setHeader("content-Type", "application/zip; charset=utf-8");
            res.setHeader("content-Length", response.length);
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${filename}`);
            res.send(response);
  });
```

The response of the API tried from postman is as follows
[image]

I am not able to correctly send and create the zip file.

Comment: what is result.length?

Answer (score 2):

Try using different charset and result length may be wrong i think, I am not getting where it comes from.
you can also write file on local instance and send path to the client.

Comment: result.length was a typo. I have tried writing to file also however the saved file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

On above snippet, change the content-length from result.length to response.length

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. tried number of ways to fix the issue but still NO luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to pipe the request with the response that you are getting from the method.